# MULTI SEARCH PHP

Tags: php

Can anyone help me to figure out the error in my code? i want to display data through two input search..my code goes like these.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Studid</td>
        <td>Course</td>
    </tr>

 <?php
    include ("connect.php");


    if(isset($_POST['submit']))

    {
    $studno=$_POST['idsearch'];
    $scourse=$_POST['coursesearch'];
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cfnr WHERE studid= ".$studno." AND course=".$scourse."");

    }

    ?>


    <?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))

    {


 }  

?> 
  <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['studid'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['course'];?></td>
    </tr>



</table>
```

i got this error in my screen.

**"mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in "**

thanks! :)

Comment: ignoring the deprecated library (use `mysqli_*` or PDO) and the SQL Injection vulnerability the error tells you the problem. `$sql` is a boolean. that means there's something wrong with your connection or your query.

Comment: Check $result before passing it to mysql_fetch_array. You'll find that it's false because the query failed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array()/mysqli\_fetch\_assoc()/mysqli\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1)

Comment: hey guys do i have to change it?

Answer (score -1):

You should use a bit of debugging. Try this:

```
$sql   =  "SELECT * FROM cfnr WHERE studid= '".$studno."' AND course = '".$scourse."'";
$query =  mysql_query($sql) or die(__LINE__."has an error: ".mysql_error());  // Gives an error if there's a syntax error

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
exit;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     /* Other code */
}
```

Comment: i tried it. but it says that my "query was empty".  what will i do with that? do i have error in my select query?

Comment: Where exactly is it showing that? Okay, let me modify my answer and let me know what you get now.

Comment: when i run it in my page. ok tnx.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your sql with below line :

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cfnr WHERE studid= ".$studno." AND course=".$scourse."") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: i did it sir but it displays the same error, undefined variable in while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) and mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is your `$sql variable is within the if condition and if your if condition fails there is no scope of $sql outside of if condition

Instead of

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
```

Use

```
while($row=@mysql_fetch_array($sql))
```

you will not get this error.

Comment: and also put your  <tr> section within the while loop and your while loop within the if condition

Comment: i did it nothing displays in my page.

Answer (score -1):

("SELECT * FROM cfnr WHERE studid= '$studno' AND course ='$scourse.'") or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score -1):

Change the code :

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
```

to

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
```

and also change this code:

```
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cfnr WHERE studid= ".$studno." AND course=".$scourse."");
```

to

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cfnr WHERE studid= '$studno' AND course='$scourse'");
```

Not only that, the close brace of the `isset()` should be on before your (`?>`) last closing php tag.

Change the code :

```
include ("connect.php");
```

to

```
include 'connect.php';
```